# how to reduce clickhouse memory usage or release memory manually

Tags: memory, clickhouse

i'm new about clickhouse, i have about 3 billion data in clickhouse 64G ram.

INSERT INTO a_table SELECT * FORM src_table WHERE create_time >= ? AND create_time <= ?

When executing this sql, code 241 is randomly returned

SELECT
*,
formatReadableSize(value) AS b
FROM system.asynchronous_metrics
WHERE metric LIKE '%em%'
ORDER BY b DESC

```
┌─metric───────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────value─┬─b──────────┐
│ FilesystemLogsPathTotalBytes             │          105150078976 │ 97.93 GiB  │
│ FilesystemMainPathUsedBytes              │          889244708864 │ 828.17 GiB │
│ MemoryVirtual                            │           86271520768 │ 80.35 GiB  │
│ MemoryDataAndStack                       │           81446019072 │ 75.85 GiB  │
│ jemalloc.epoch                           │                  7976 │ 7.79 KiB   │
│ OSMemoryFreePlusCached                   │            7745302528 │ 7.21 GiB   │
│ OSMemoryTotal                            │           66174210048 │ 61.63 GiB  │
│ OSMemoryAvailable                        │            6853541888 │ 6.38 GiB   │
│ FilesystemLogsPathTotalINodes            │               6553600 │ 6.25 MiB   │
│ FilesystemLogsPathAvailableINodes        │               6397780 │ 6.10 MiB   │
│ jemalloc.arenas.all.dirty_purged         │             625232220 │ 596.27 MiB │
│ FilesystemLogsPathAvailableBytes         │           61849862144 │ 57.60 GiB  │
│ jemalloc.mapped                          │           58842886144 │ 54.80 GiB  │
│ jemalloc.resident                        │           58749423616 │ 54.71 GiB  │
│ MemoryResident                           │           58665074688 │ 54.64 GiB  │
│ jemalloc.active                          │           58473361408 │ 54.46 GiB  │
│ jemalloc.allocated                       │           57016602472 │ 53.10 GiB  │
│ jemalloc.arenas.all.muzzy_purged         │             483548433 │ 461.15 MiB │
│ FilesystemLogsPathUsedBytes              │           43300216832 │ 40.33 GiB  │
│ OSMemoryCached                           │            4472168448 │ 4.17 GiB   │
│ MemoryCode                               │             366669824 │ 349.68 MiB │
│ jemalloc.arenas.all.pdirty               │                  3830 │ 3.74 KiB   │
│ OSMemoryFreeWithoutCached                │            3273134080 │ 3.05 GiB   │
│ jemalloc.metadata                        │             262799792 │ 250.63 MiB │
│ MemoryShared                             │             253267968 │ 241.54 MiB │
│ FilesystemMainPathUsedINodes             │                215867 │ 210.81 KiB │
│ FilesystemMainPathTotalBytes             │         3170529116160 │ 2.88 TiB   │
│ FilesystemMainPathAvailableBytes         │         2281284407296 │ 2.07 TiB   │
│ FilesystemMainPathTotalINodes            │             196608000 │ 187.50 MiB │
│ FilesystemMainPathAvailableINodes        │             196392133 │ 187.29 MiB │
│ jemalloc.retained                        │           19604230144 │ 18.26 GiB  │
│ FilesystemLogsPathUsedINodes             │                155820 │ 152.17 KiB │
│ jemalloc.arenas.all.pactive              │              14275723 │ 13.61 MiB  │
│ jemalloc.arenas.all.pmuzzy               │                  1394 │ 1.36 KiB   │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Can I release memory by manually ?

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-who-ate-my-memory/

Comment: Give the output for `SET send_logs_level='trace'; SELECT * FORM src_table WHERE create_time >= ? AND create_time <= ?`